# Is there any way to edit a UITextField with dictation only?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I mean I do not want to use a keyboard. I have a button that I want the user to press that will trigger the microphone and input speech into the textField.

I've searched everywhere for tutorials on how to do this; I'm not finding anything. Is it impossible?

Comment: Do you mean dictation or do you mean you want a sound recording?

Comment: I want speech input.

Comment: In order to type text? Or to be stored as a sound recording?

Comment: Which one? The text one? Is there any reason you want to do this? For me it would be much much much easier to enter text using a keyboard. Plus you have to accommodate people with speech impediments or people who can't speak at all.

Comment: If you tap the text field, a keyboard appears. I just want the speech button for faster input in case there's no need for a keyboard. The app requires only two to three words at a time, so the keyboard may end up taking longer than just saying it.

Comment: Are you trying to record the voice and convert to text and input it in the textfield? If yes then you can use some speech to text frameworks. Like http://www.politepix.com/openears/ or https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone. Also have a look at http://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=home see example http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri